# DIV with max height of body and flex does not work correctly on IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have the following CSS and HTML as the minimal to reproduce the issue. On Chrome all good. IE11 not. Is there a way to fix the CSS and HTML so it works on both Chrome and IE11?

```
<html>
    <style>
        .max-box {
            background-color: #00e;
            width: 100px;
            max-height: 80%;
            padding: 5px;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
        .fixed-box {
            background-color: #00e;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .content {
            background-color: #0e0;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: #e00;
            display: flex;
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="max-box" style="float: left">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <span>a1</span><span>a2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <span>b1</span><span>b2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-box" style="float: left">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <span>a1</span><span>a2</span><span>a3</span><span>a4</span><span>a5</span><span>a6</span><span>a7</span><span>a8</span><span>a9</span>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <span>b1</span><span>b2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fixed-box">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <span>a1</span><span>a2</span><span>a3</span><span>a4</span><span>a5</span><span>a6</span><span>a7</span><span>a8</span><span>a9</span>
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <span>b1</span><span>b2</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the requirements are what Chrome is behaving:

1. Box 1 will not take up the space below if the content is little.
2. Box 2 will take up at most 80% height of the browser and the content is scrollable. Responsive if the browser height changes.
3. Box 3 is fixed height and the content is scrollable and spaced the same as box 2.

What IE11 failed are:

1. Box 1 and Box 2 does not make content scrollable when browser height changed to smaller than the content.
2. Box 3 content is scrollable but the values all cramped.

Comment: Need More clarification on this what want.

Comment: @ChandreshPolra Thanks for your interest. What else is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

as this seems to be unanswered I will try to give you my two cents. IE and other browsers usually need autoprefixer for flexbox to work properly. Try the following, which is exactly your code run trough autoprefixer

```
        .max-box {
            background-color: #00e;
            width: 100px;
            max-height: 80%;
            padding: 5px;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
                    flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
        .fixed-box {
            background-color: #00e;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
                    flex: 1 1 auto;
        }
        .wrapper {
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
                    flex: 1 1 auto;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                -ms-flex-direction: column;
                    flex-direction: column;
        }
        .content {
            background-color: #0e0;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
                -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
                    flex: 1 1 auto;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
                -ms-flex-direction: column;
                    flex-direction: column;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        .footer {
            background-color: #e00;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-flex: 0;
                -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
                    flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
```